# Rich Faces: How to get rid of paddings in panels?

Tags: richfaces

I want to get rid of the padding between the border and the gradient:

[image]

In this file I load an own css class:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css" />
    <title>Our Application</title>
</h:head>
```

In default.css, I set those parameters:

```
.rf-p {
    padding:0;
}
/*header*/

.rf-p-hdr {
    padding:0;
}

/*body*/
.rf-p-b {
    padding:0;
}
```

But when I debug this with firebug, I see that Richfaces always overwrite it:
[image]

How can I vanquish this?

By the way: I could format the code within the xhtml:

```
    <rich:panel id="mainPanel" header="Main Menu" style="padding:0">
        <h:form>
        </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
```

But at first, this is no solution and secondly, it only covers .rf-p and not .rf-p-hdr so there would still be a padding. And it doesn't help too if I set those attributes:

```
    <rich:panel id="mainPanel" header="Main Menu" headerClass="noborder" bodyClass="noborder" styleClass="noborder">
        <h:form>
        </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
```

in css file:

```
.noborder  {
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always force to override the declared style:

```
.noborder  {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

or :

```
.rf-p {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.rf-p-hdr {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.rf-p-b {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```